# Rails 3 validates uniqueness with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, unique

I have model Post with boolean field default. Post belongs to User. I want to ensure that there is only one default (e.g. set to true) post for user. Tried this:

```
validates :default, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }, if: :default?
```

but it allows to create two Posts with `default: true, user_id: 1`

Can you please help me?

P.S. this construction works perfectly for `validates :name, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }, unless: :default?` may be there is something wrong with booleans?

Comment: What if you drop the final `?`

Comment: +1 ^  Drop the `?`.. also curious if `default` is reserved.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Problem solved. After 10 `rails s` restarts it just started to work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this validation:

```
validate :only_one_default_post_per_user

def only_one_default_post_per_user
  if Post.exists?(:user_id => user_id, :default => true)
    errors.add("Error! There is a default post for this user!")
  end
end
```